# Run Code-first update-database gives an error against GoDaddy server DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a web hosting and I upload my entire project throw FTP to GoDaddy but I stuck when I change the connection string of my project to one in the server i run `Update-database` in package-manager I get a migration error for one of the migrations telling that **cannot insert null in column**.

I tried to use a generated script using this command:
`Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0` 
I don't know if this command is the right command!!

now I don't know what to do? all things works fine on my local machine and with my local connection string
what can I do to run the migrations in the right way?

Comment: That is the correct command to generate the script. Did you get an error? Once you have that script you can step through it.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have new column in TableX.

This column not allow null values.

In TableX there are exist data.

Migrator can`t fill this column in exists rows.

a) Allow null for new column

b) Delete all from table

c) look about default values for new columns

Comment: I revert to last good migration after this i allow null for the forgien key that causes the problem.